# how to append the length after found "#0"

Tags: java

My data format will be like "#9#0000075".

How to delete "#9" and start with "#0" and the next value. How to get count before "#0".

For info: " #9" sometime not only 3 characters, may be more or less. but it sure need start with  "#0".

```
StringBuilder gate = new StringBuilder();
int count = 1;
String header = "";
String oldHeader = "";

public void processRawPacket(int i) throws Exception {
    try {
        gate.append((char) i);
        oldHeader = gate.toString();

        for (int index = 0; index <= oldHeader.length(); index++) {
            if (oldHeader == "#0") {
                gate.append(oldHeader);
            }
            index++;
        }
        process = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println(expMsg + "processRawPacket(i): " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        StringWriter stack = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stack));
        out.println("Caught exception packet; decorating with appropriate status template : " + stack.toString());

        resetPacket();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will there be at most one occurrence of `#0`?

Comment: Yes, but at middle of the value

Answer (score 3):

You have a potential issue with String comparison. Operator `==` is for reference comparing. To compare two string use `.equals()` method.
Precisely, this code

```
if (oldHeader == "#0") {
    gate.append(oldHeader);
}
```

Should be

```
if("#0".equals(oldHeader)) {
    gate.append(oldHeader);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use delimiter and then add it to the array. Then add one to consider the length of # also.

```
String s="#9#0000075";
String[] ss=s.split("#");
```

Just note while playing with length to consider # make it count by adding one to the length.

This was you can separately handle them and use the lengths.

Comment: i can't split like this cause # i need use for others purpose..if do like this i need add bac again for infront value 0000075

Answer (score 2):

You could use the native String methods:

```
final String header = "#0";
String pkg = "#9#048965648";
int oldheader = pkg.indexOf(header);    // Yields 2 here
pkg = pkg.substring(oldheader); // Yields #048965648
```

The `str.indexOf(searchString)` method returns the first index at which the `searchString` starts in `str`. If `searchString` cannot be found, it returns  `-1`. Cf. [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) If the header you wish to remove is *also* `#0`, then [lastIndexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)) is what you’re looking for, supposing then that there are at most two occurences of `#0` – When the old and new headers are both `#0`.

`substring` (in this form) returns the string beginning at the specified position, which (here) effectively clips the header you wish to remove. ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))). Should you want to retain the original header, use the two-integer variant [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) with `0` as the begin index.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new in programming.. if String pkg = "#9#048965648"  is String pkg = "#0#048965648"; how i wan find is #048965648?

Comment: Thank you very much...i get the answer